# Checking for type errors in PHP 7+

Tags: php, types, continuous-integration, php-7, type-hinting

How do you check for type errors in a CI/CD setup for modern PHP projects using extensive type-hinting and return type declarations?

Previous questions on this site regarding this topic seem to be very old and not relevant to the new typing features of PHP 7.0 and 7.1.

PHP lint checking doesn't detect type errors so when test coverage is missing, it can result in runtime errors that should be able to be avoided.  Does anyone have an automated way to detect invalid parameters or return types in their CI setup to provide extra assurance beyond written tests?

P.S.  I know I can review my own code with IDE features, but I'm more concerned with a CI approach involving a project that has multiple authors.

Comment: [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) is pretty good at this.

Comment: "when test coverage is missing" sounds like you need something to check your code coverage.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thank you, I remember seeing this tool before but forgot the name of it.  Looks great.

Comment: @Sammitch definitely, the end goal is to have more complete code coverage but on this large existing project, I'm looking for something to more quickly cover the gaps until we reach that point.